# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$. If the directional derivatives are continuous, does this mean $f$ is differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

There is a result which states that for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ if all its partial derivatives exist and are continuous then the total derivative $Df$ exists.

If I calculate the directional derivatives along $n$ independent directions different from the canonical basis $\lbrace\vec{e}_1,\ldots,\vec{e}_n\rbrace$ and they are all continous, does the above result still hold?

Comment: Then the partial derivatives can be written as a linear combination of directional derivatives in the independent directions and so would be continuous.

Comment: @Cristian: The theorem you cite has an additional hypothesis, along the lines of: "If all the partials of $f$ exists and are continuous _in some open set_ $U$, then $f$ is differentiable in $U$". (There exist functions discontinuous at the origin even though _all_ directional derivatives exist at the origin.) So, when you say you calculate directional derivatives, are you doing so throughout an open set, or only at one point? The distinction is crucial.

Comment: @user86418 You are right, I hadn't considered that. The question remains the same though, with the added assumption that $f$'s directional derivatives exist in some $U$.

Comment: @SrinivasK I think this pretty much answers the question. Maybe you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then the partial derivatives can be written as a linear combination of directional derivatives in the independent directions and so would be conntinuous.